# Running Arara from TeXworks on a mac

Tags: mactex, texworks, arara

It took me a long time to get arara to work from within TeXworks on OS X 10.14 or 10.15. I would get two errors:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/scripts/arara/arara.sh: line 8: kpsewhich: command not found
Unable to access jarfile
```

I eventually found the problems: the system path was not inherited by the sh script and the scriptname variable contains the file extension (so jar was getting set to arara.sh.jar instead of arara.jar).

I fixed it by adding:

```
PATH=/Library/TeX/texbin:$PATH
```

To the first line of the arara.sh file and then I changed

```
jar="$scriptname.jar"
```

to

```
jar="arara.jar"
```

Once I made those two changes, it worked like a charm.

Is this a known issue?

Edit: One thing to add, if I call arara directly from terminal, it works correctly without modifications to the sh file. I only have issues when calling it from TeXworks.

Comment: Welcome! What is `sh` on your system? For example, what does `sh --version` give?

Comment: @cfr GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: Maybe ask the author of `arara`. I don't know how Macs are set up now. There's no reason you should have to make those changes. Especially, the second one sounds very odd indeed.

Comment: I was able to change how I call arara from TeXworks from directly calling arara.sh with the full path to calling "arara" and that removed the need for the edit to the jar definition. The first edit still seems to be required.

Comment: What do `echo $PATH` and `which kpsewhich` return on your system?