# Arara Error: Unable to access jarfile

Tags: texshop, arara, java

I am trying to compile a LaTeX document using [arara](https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/arara) on the command line, but I get a `Error: Unable to access jarfile` notification.This happens even when I do only `arara -V` for the version. Strangely enough, if I compile the document in TeXShop using the arara-engine, everything works fine, even though (as far as I can see), the TexShop script does nothing more than making sure that arara is on the path. This seems to be the opposite of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512037/running-arara-from-texworks-on-a-mac). I have used arara to compile tex documents many times before (although haven't used it much lately), also on my current laptop, and never had this issue.

I've searched for the error on the internet, and see many other questions and solutions. The problems seems to be with Java, but I did not find a solution that I could apply to my problem. I know nothing about Java, so I don't really know what to look for next.

I have re-installed arara v5.1.3 using the TeX Live Installer, and have `openjdk 15.0.1` from Homebrew. TeXShop is Version 4.44. Using macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

Comment: By the way, that option to get the version is either -V (not -v) or --version. The -v option is  for verbose.

Comment: @HerbSchulz edited as per your comment